# Avoiding leakage on my random forest?

Tags: random-forest, parameter, experiments

I am training a random forest model. I am wondering if it is safe (leakage?) to use on my training set the parameter **average price of a car** calculated using all my data points. The issue is that some of these data are used to test my model as well. I try to give an example:

Say, the average for that car model is composed of 5 cars and it is 10,000 EUR. I used 3 of these cars to train my random forest. For each car, I provide (besides other parameters) the average price of all cars (10,000) and the price of that particular car (say 8,000) as input.

For my testing, I would still provide the price of all cars (10,000) and the price of each particular car (13,000) as input. I want to know if that's leakage, since the 13,000 (now on the testing set) was also used to obtain the 10,000 average.

I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't leakage. However, this is still a problem. You are training your data with testing data; basically your model is cheating by looking at the answers ahead of time

Comment: I will assume you are training this forest to make some predictions. If so, here is an important fact about predictive models: the predictors should be measurable at the time of forecasting. Will the average car price (as you computed it) be a meaningfull, measurable predictor at the time you want to use the forest to make a forecast?

Comment: you can avoid the leakage problem by splitting the data set prior to calculating the average for that particular car. Once you have the untampered test set, you calculate the average from the train set and use those values (that way you aren't looking at test data for this information).